# how to deploy a web service with external libraries using netbeans?

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, glassfish

I created a EJB module and added a webservice. I added external .jars which needs to run the webservice. My problem is when I tries to deploy, it gives me an error saying, "GlassFish Server 4.1, deploy, Server returned HTTP response code: 400". When I deploy a EJB module which does not use any external libraries for the webservice, I can deploy it successfully. So, problem occurs when I add some external libraries. I don't know how to fix this.Please help me. my directory structure looks like following.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create an "Enterprise Application" without modules:

[image: Imgur]

Right click on the created project and "Add Java EE Module":

[image: Imgur]

On the properties of the created project, in the "Packaging" category, add you libraries into the *lib* folder.

[image: Imgur]

e.g. I added the MySQL driver. Of course, you need add the libraries in your module, as you've already done.

Now deploys your application again.

Comment: I tried out as you said. But again it gives me a build failure message.What can I do?

Comment: I added the libraries to EJB module also. But in ImageCompare.jar I can't see the added libraries. Can it be the problem?

Comment: With this way, you deploy a EAR file. The structure of that file is similar to http://www.horstmann.com/elvis/quiz-ear.png Looking for in the dist folder and open the EAR file generated and see the lib folder.

Comment: I can see all the libraries inside lib folder. But now, how can I run the webservice inside the imageCompare EJB module?

Comment: Did you tried deploying the EAR in your glassfish? I mean, using the Web Console of Glassfish.

Comment: I write clicked on the Enterprise application project and clicked on 'deploy'. But it it failed.

Comment: Works for me... Humm... I'm using the last [development version](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/) of NetBeans. I don't know. Did you tried uploading the EAR using the console: http://localhost:4848

Comment: I tried out deploying through the console, But I'm getting an error "Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app. Please see server.log for more details. Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.appclient.server.core.AppClientDeployer prepare method : java.lang.RuntimeException Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.appclient.server.core.AppClientDeployer prepare method : java.lang.RuntimeException"